# What is the best way to display last value in jQuery dependable drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

If we use the following as an example, how can I have the form maintain the last default selection for the dropdown fields? Rather than displaying "choose county" how can it have the stored variable first if present, else "choose county" 2nd if no variable is known?

If this form is revisited or edited the selection has defaulted to the 'choose county' and 'choose holiday park' defaults, I'd like it to recall the selection the user made, only showing those titles if its a brand new first time submission.
Is it possible, is it explained well?
Regards

```js
var myJson = {
  "property_city_front_autointernal": [{
    "name": "Cornwall",
    "id": "Cornwall",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Crantock Beach  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Crantock Beach  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Holywell Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Holywell Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Looe Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Looe Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Lizard Point  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Lizard Point  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Newquay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Newquay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sea Acres  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sea Acres  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "St Minver  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "St Minver  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "White Acres  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "White Acres  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Perran Sands  (Haven)",
        "id": "Perran Sands  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Riviere Sands  (Haven)",
        "id": "Riviere Sands  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "St Ives Holiday Village  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "St Ives Holiday Village  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Killigarth Manor  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Killigarth Manor  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Perran View  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Perran View  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Tolroy Manor  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Tolroy Manor  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Trelawne Manor  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Trelawne Manor  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Widemouth Bay  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Widemouth Bay  (John Fowler)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Devon",
    "id": "Devon",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Devon Cliffs  (Haven)",
        "id": "Devon Cliffs  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Bideford Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Bideford Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Challaborough Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Challaborough Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Ruda  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Ruda  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Torquay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Torquay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Waterside   (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Waterside   (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Tarka  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Tarka  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Riviera Bay  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Riviera Bay  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Landscove  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Landscove  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Golden Sands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Golden Sands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Dawlish Sands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Dawlish Sands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Combe Martin  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Combe Martin  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandaway Beach  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Sandaway Beach  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "South Bay  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "South Bay  (John Fowler)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Somerset",
    "id": "Somerset",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Sandy Glade  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Sandy Glade  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandy Meadows  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Sandy Meadows  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Burnham on Sea  (Haven)",
        "id": "Burnham on Sea  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Doniford Bay  (Haven)",
        "id": "Doniford Bay  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Wales",
    "id": "Wales",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Llanrhidian  (John Fowler)",
        "id": "Llanrhidian  (John Fowler)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Brynowen  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Brynowen  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Carmarthen Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Carmarthen Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Pendine Sands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Pendine Sands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Trecco Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Trecco Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Ty Mawr  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Ty Mawr  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Kiln Park  (Haven)",
        "id": "Kiln Park  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Greenacres  (Haven)",
        "id": "Greenacres  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Hafan-Y-Mor  (Haven)",
        "id": "Hafan-Y-Mor  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Lydstep Beach  (Haven)",
        "id": "Lydstep Beach  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Penally Court  (Haven)",
        "id": "Penally Court  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Presthaven  (Haven)",
        "id": "Presthaven  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Quay West  (Haven)",
        "id": "Quay West  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Yorkshire",
    "id": "Yorkshire",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Skirlington Leisure Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
        "id": "Skirlington Leisure Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Gransmoor Lodge  (Skirlington leisure)",
        "id": "Gransmoor Lodge  (Skirlington leisure)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Springfield Farm  (Skirlington leisure)",
        "id": "Springfield Farm  (Skirlington leisure)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Glen Esk Holiday Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
        "id": "Glen Esk Holiday Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Atwick Cliff Top Welford Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
        "id": "Atwick Cliff Top Welford Park  (Skirlington leisure)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Barmston Beach  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Barmston Beach  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Cayton Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Cayton Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Skipsea Sands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Skipsea Sands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Withernsea Sands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Withernsea Sands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue Dolphin  (Haven)",
        "id": "Blue Dolphin  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Primrose Valley  (Haven)",
        "id": "Primrose Valley  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Reighton Sands  (Haven)",
        "id": "Reighton Sands  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Thornwick Bay  (Haven)",
        "id": "Thornwick Bay  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Dorset",
    "id": "Dorset",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Littlesea  (Haven)",
        "id": "Littlesea  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Rockley Park  (Haven)",
        "id": "Rockley Park  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Seaview  (Haven)",
        "id": "Seaview  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Weymouth Bay  (Haven)",
        "id": "Weymouth Bay  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandford  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sandford  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Warmwell  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Warmwell  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "West Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "West Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandhills  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Sandhills  (Park Holiday)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Lancashire",
    "id": "Lancashire",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Ocean Edge  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Ocean Edge  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Regent Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Regent Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Todber Valley  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Todber Valley  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Cala Gran  (Haven)",
        "id": "Cala Gran  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Marton Mere  (Haven)",
        "id": "Marton Mere  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Lincolnshire",
    "id": "Lincolnshire",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Southview  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Southview  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sunnydale  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sunnydale  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Golden Sands  (Haven)",
        "id": "Golden Sands  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Thorpe Park  (Haven)",
        "id": "Thorpe Park  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Kent",
    "id": "Kent",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Romney Sands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Romney Sands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "St. Margaret's Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "St. Margaret's Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Allhallows  (Haven)",
        "id": "Allhallows  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Seaview  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Seaview  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "New Beach  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "New Beach  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Marlie  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Marlie  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Harts  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Harts  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Birchington Vale  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Birchington Vale  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Alberta  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Alberta  (Park Holiday)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Sussex",
    "id": "Sussex",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Winchelsea Sands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Winchelsea Sands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Rye Harbour   (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Rye Harbour   (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Pevensey Bay  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Pevensey Bay  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Coghurst Hall  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Coghurst Hall  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Chichester Lakeside  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Chichester Lakeside  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Beauport  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Beauport  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Camber Sands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Camber Sands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Church Farm  (Haven)",
        "id": "Church Farm  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Combe Haven  (Haven)",
        "id": "Combe Haven  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Hampshire / Isle of Wight",
    "id": "Hampshire / Isle of Wight",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Solent Breezes  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Solent Breezes  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Hayling Island  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Hayling Island  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Landguard  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Landguard  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Lower Hyde  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Lower Hyde  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Nodes Point  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Nodes Point  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Thorness Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Thorness Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Essex",
    "id": "Essex",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Steeple Bay  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Steeple Bay  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "St Osyth Beach  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "St Osyth Beach  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Seawick  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Seawick  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Martello Beach  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Martello Beach  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Dovercourt  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Dovercourt  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "West Mersea  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "West Mersea  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Oaklands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Oaklands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Coopers Beach  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Coopers Beach  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Highfield Grange  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Highfield Grange  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Naze Marine  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Naze Marine  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Valley Farm  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Valley Farm  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Weeley Bridge  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Weeley Bridge  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "The Orchards  (Haven)",
        "id": "The Orchards  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Suffolk",
    "id": "Suffolk",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Suffolk Sands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Suffolk Sands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Felixstowe Beach  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Felixstowe Beach  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Carlton Meres  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Carlton Meres  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Broadland Sands  (Park Holiday)",
        "id": "Broadland Sands  (Park Holiday)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Kessingland Beach  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Kessingland Beach  (Parkdean)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Scotland",
    "id": "Scotland",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Craig Tara  (Haven)",
        "id": "Craig Tara  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Seton Sands  (Haven)",
        "id": "Seton Sands  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Eyemouth  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Eyemouth  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Grannie's Heilan' Hame  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Grannie's Heilan' Hame  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Nairn Lochloy  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Nairn Lochloy  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandylands  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sandylands  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Southerness  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Southerness  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sundrum Castle  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sundrum Castle  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Tummel Valley  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Tummel Valley  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Wemyss Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Wemyss Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Cumbria",
    "id": "Cumbria",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Fallbarrow  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Fallbarrow  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Gatebeck  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Gatebeck  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Limefitt Park (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Limefitt Park (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "White Cross Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "White Cross Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Lakeland  (Haven)",
        "id": "Lakeland  (Haven)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Durham",
    "id": "Durham",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Crimdon Dene  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Crimdon Dene  (Parkdean)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Norfolk",
    "id": "Norfolk",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Caister  (Haven)",
        "id": "Caister  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Hopton  (Haven)",
        "id": "Hopton  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Seashore  (Haven)",
        "id": "Seashore  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Wild Duck  (Haven)",
        "id": "Wild Duck  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Breydon Water  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Breydon Water  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "California Cliffs  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "California Cliffs  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Cherry Tree  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Cherry Tree  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Heacham Beach  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Heacham Beach  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Manor Park  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Manor Park  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Summerfields  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Summerfields  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Vauxhall  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Vauxhall  (Parkdean)",
      },
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Northumberland",
    "id": "Northumberland",
    "property_area_front": [

      {
        "name": "Berwick  (Haven)",
        "id": "Berwick  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Haggerston Castle  (Haven)",
        "id": "Haggerston Castle  (Haven)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Church Point  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Church Point  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Cresswell Towers  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Cresswell Towers  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sandy Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Sandy Bay  (Parkdean)",
      },
      {
        "name": "Whitley Bay  (Parkdean)",
        "id": "Whitley Bay  (Parkdean)",
      }
    ]
  }]

}



$.each(myJson.property_city_front_autointernal, function(index, value) {
  $("#property_city_front_autointernal").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
});

$('#property_city_front_autointernal').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  for (var i = 0; i < myJson.property_city_front_autointernal.length; i++) {
    if (myJson.property_city_front_autointernal[i].id == $(this).val()) {
      $('#property_area_front').html('<option value="Choose Holiday Park">Choose Holiday Park</option>');
      $.each(myJson.property_city_front_autointernal[i].property_area_front, function(index, value) {
        $("#property_area_front").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
        $("select option[value*='Choose Holiday Park']").prop('disabled', true);

      });
    }
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#edit_prop_1").attr("disabled", true);

  $('#property_city_front_autointernal').change(function() {
    $("#edit_prop_1").attr("disabled", true);
  });

  $('#property_area_front').change(function() {
    if ($('property_area_front').val() == "Choose Holiday Park") {
      $("#edit_prop_1").attr("disabled", true);

    } else {
      $("#edit_prop_1").attr("disabled", false);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="property_city_front_autointernal" name="property_city_front">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose County</option>
</select>
<select id="property_area_front" name="property_area_front">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Holiday Park</option>
</select>
<div class="col-md-12" style="display: inline-block;">
  <input type="submit" class="wpb_btn-info wpb_btn-small wpestate_vc_button  vc_button" id="edit_prop_1" value="Next" />
```

Comment: You can save the selections in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Then when you reopen the page, set the values of the dropdowns from that.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by assigning it say $property_city and $property_area, thats how it used to function before I made the selections with a dependable menu.

Comment: You mean on the server when you're creating the HTML? When you're looping over the possible values to put in `<option>`, you can compare `$property_city` with the current `$city` in the loop, and add the `selected` attribute if they match.